# How to change a function that has references to objects in a previous scope

Tags: javascript, function, reference, scope, edit

I would like to replace the code of a function but it has references inside another scope. I'm not sure I'm using the correct terminology so this is better explained by the code.

```
RenderEngineWebGL = (function () {
//code that creates textCanvas somewhere here
    re.createTextTexture = function(textureId, fontName, 
          size, color, text, outlineSize, outlineColor) {
...
...
    var ctx = textCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = fontString;
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    }
...
return re;
}());
```

I tried to just edit this by changing RenderEngineWebGL.createTextTexture to how I want the function to work.

```
RenderEngineWebGL.createTextTexture = function(textureId, fontName, 
          size, color, text, outlineSize, outlineColor) {
    ...
    ...
    console.log(text);//Whatever I Want
    size = 50;        //to change here


    var ctx = textCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = fontString;
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    }
```

This won't work because textCanvas is not defined outside of that scope. I've temporarily solved this by using a chrome extension and replacing the whole code with my code, but when the code is updated I have to manually put these edits back in.

textCanvas is not the only problem, so finding that canvas will not help. There are other references that cause errors that I did not include.

If I were able to edit this function without having to replace all of the code in the rest of the script then the only time I would need to update it is when the part that I changed has changed.

How can I change a function that has references to objects like textCanvas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access textCanvas outside the anonymous function as it is lexically bound to that function scope.
Your only option is to change `RenderEngineWebGL`, so `textCanvas` will be accessable to other scopes.
For example you can do this inside `RenderEngineWebGL`:

```
re.textCanvas = textCanvas;
```

and then you can get it outside the function by using `RenderEngineWebGL.textCanvas`.

A better way would be to create a public "method" to get the private variable:

```
re.getTextCanvas = function() {
    return textCanvas;
};
```

Comment: That's the problem. This isn't my code so I can not change the code like that. I'm not sure there is a way to do what I'm looking for.